# StormCrawler debug logs in local mode

Tags: logging, apache-storm, stormcrawler

When I inspect the source of StormCrawler, there are lot of helpful debug logs. But putting a log4j.xml and adding a logger will not print those in the console. What are the steps I should follow to enable logging in StormCrawler?

Comment: how do you run the topology? storm jar ... ?

Comment: Yes! `storm jar target/crawler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  org.apache.storm.flux.Flux --local crawler.flux --sleep 60000` to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

You should see the logs on the console when running the command above.

The log4j config used is the one from Storm e.g. */usr/share/apache-storm-1.2.2/log4j2/* and it is used in deployed mode as well.

You can specify the location of the logs for the deployed mode in the storm conf e.g. */usr/share/apache-storm-1.2.2/conf/storm.yaml*

by setting

```
storm.log.dir: "/var/log/storm"
```

Comment: With above command, I can see only INFO logs. I want to turn on DEBUG logs. Also editing apache-storm-1.2.2/log4j2/ didn't work. I have debugged the code and found out logging configurations are picking from storm-core jar (there is a log4j2.xml inside the jar).

However by passing -Dlog4j.configurationFile option to above command, I could see DEBUG logs.