# Logging DEBUG messages in Stormcrawler

Tags: logging, stormcrawler

after looking at [this previous question on logging in the StormCrawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53439705/stormcrawler-debug-logs-in-local-mode), it was not completely clear to me how to enable the logging of DEBUG messages when running the StormCrawler.

By default, I only see the [INFO] logs. Is there some parameter or configuration to set when submitting a topology?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Storm command-line client has a tool [set_log_level](https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.4.0/Command-line-client.html#set_log_level) which allows to change the log level dynamically (and temporarily), eg.

```
storm set_log_level MyTopology -l com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.FetcherBolt=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

and it can be done from the UI https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.2.3/dynamic-log-level-settings.html